# How to turn a range value to a double (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

So I want to make a function that takes a value in a cell to make some calculations, but whenever I try to get the value from the cell rather than hard-code it I get a **#VALUE!** error whenever the function is run. Whereas this did not happen when the value is hard-coded.

I believe that this is because the Range.Value returns a Variant, but I don't know how to turn the data to a double so that the function works right.

```
Function IfMissionarySupplies(Missionary_Type As String) As Double
Wb = ThisWorkbook 'Wb is a global variable.
Dim Elder_Supplies, Sister_Supplies As Double
Elder_Supplies = Workbooks(Wb).Worksheets("Control Variables").Range("C11").Value
Sister_Supplies = Workbooks(Wb).Worksheets("Control Variables").Range("C14").Value
If Missionary_Type = "Sisters" Then
    IfMissionarySupplies = Sister_Supplies
    Exit Function
ElseIf Missionary_Type = "Elders" Then
    IfMissionarySupplies = Elder_Supplies
End If 
End Function
```

I've searched over and over in the internet, but to no avail. I am also new to VBA so I might be overlooking something obvious to more experienced VBA developers.

Thanks!

Comment: Elder_Supplies is implicitly typed as a variant.  Use Dim Elder_Supplies As Double instead.

Comment: It is a double, since Elder_Supplies and Sister_Supplies were both declared as Double, check the third line.

Comment: What are the values in those ranges, C11 and C14

Comment: **Missionary_Type** is not defined anywhere in the UDF

Comment: They are numbers, but they are formatted as currency, though, I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent it is the parameter

Comment: @CarlosJimenez why don't you debug it and see what the values are being set to

Comment: Missionary_Type is the only parameter the function receives...

Comment: **Wb = ThisWorkbook.Name** to use it the way you are doing.

Comment: I tried already using MsgBox to check what was being received as a value, but everytime I try to run it nothing shows up.

Comment: as @Mike already pointed out...Elder_Supplies is dim'd as a variant (I know you have it on the same line as the double declaration, but VBA doesn't work that way...you have to dim each variable independently.  The ones that aren't explicitly defined get Variant.  Also, what's the value of Workbooks(Wb).Worksheets("Control Variables").Range("C11").Value?  Is it what you think it is?  You're best best is to use a break point and the Locals window to figure out the values and types of each variable and go from there.

Comment: Tried debugging further, apparently the error pops up from the very moment Wb = ThisWorkbook, is run. Tried using Wb = ThisWorkbook.Name, but it produced the same result.

Comment: Tried using the File's name instead of "ThisWorkbook" and everything started working as it should have. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the following in a standard module:

```
Function IfMissionarySupplies(Missionary_Type As String) As Double
    Wb = ThisWorkbook.Name 'Wb is a global variable.
    Dim Elder_Supplies, Sister_Supplies As Double

    Elder_Supplies = Workbooks(Wb).Worksheets("Control Variables").Range("C11").Value
    Sister_Supplies = Workbooks(Wb).Worksheets("Control Variables").Range("C14").Value

    If Missionary_Type = "Sisters" Then
        IfMissionarySupplies = Sister_Supplies
        Exit Function
    ElseIf Missionary_Type = "Elders" Then
        IfMissionarySupplies = Elder_Supplies
    End If
End Function
```

and setup the worksheet as follows:

[image]

So the above version of your *UDF* does appear to work!